# Clone or Duplicate the first object and Insert to the same list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of Phones that came from the database, and I would like to clone the first entry and insert it to the same list (updated entry).

```
    List<Phones> p = new List<Phones>
    {
        new Phones { ID = 1, Phone = "Samsung S3" },
        new Phones { ID = 2, Phone = "iPhone 5" },
        new Phones { ID = 3, Phone = "Samsung S4" },
        new Phones { ID = 4, Phone = "Samsung S5" },
        new Phones { ID = 5, Phone = "iPhone 5s" },
        new Phones { ID = 6, Phone = "iPhone 6" },
    };
```

Currently I used the below approach. but the first entry updates also.

```
    var obj = p.FirstOrDefault();
    var t = new Phones();

    t = obj;
    t.ID = 7;
    p.Add(t);


public class Phones
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public bool isChild { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class is call by reference so if you change the value is changing the first member as well. You can clone Phone, but you should implement IClonable interface, only consider this link as well [Implementing IClonable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/09/49935.aspx)

```
public class Phones : ICloneable
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public bool isChild { get; set; }

        public object Clone()
        {
            return new Phones()
            {
                ID = this.ID,
                Phone = this.Phone,
                isChild = this.isChild
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was not aware of this possibility.  Nice!  Also did not notice all the other answers before I finally figured out an answer.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're editing the same instance. You'd have to create a new object and then set the properties:

```
// this is already ok:
var obj = p.FirstOrDefault();
var t = new Phones();

// don't do this:
// t = obj;

// copy properties:
t.ID = obj.ID;
t.Phone = obj.Phone
t.isChild = obj.isChild

// add to list
p.Add(t);
```

Preferably, though, you should implement [ICloneable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) and put that code into the `Clone()` method (see Peyman's answer).

Comment: Thank you, I used your approach for my current scenario for this one. But I will give the answer to Peyman.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = p.FirstOrDefault();
```

merely assigns a reference of p to the new object obj.

```
t = obj;
```

does the same thing. Any change made to `t` will update `obj` and `p`, since they are really just references to the same object.

Copy the value of each property of `obj` (or `p`) into `t`, rather than assigning a reference to the same object.

```
t.ID = obj.ID;
t.Phone = obj.Phone;
```